# WPF change background of disabled buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to learn WPF and I have made a simple Tic Tac Toe application. The application works but I'm trying to style it a bit. I can't find out how to set the button disabled background for all my buttons (and keep the content visible). My question is how set up the code in the resource dictionary? The commented code is what I tried. To give all buttons the same style I added a resource dictionary.

The resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <!--<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate,
                                 StringFormat={}{0:d},
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Padding="4,0,0,0" />
                            </Border>-->
                            <!--<Border BorderBrush="Aquamarine" BorderThickness="1"></Border>-->
                            <!-- Outer Rectangle with rounded corners. -->
                            <!-- Present Content (text) of the button. -->                         
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
  <Application x:Class="FirstApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FirstApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,0.4,-19.2" Name="controlGrid">
        <Button x:Name="A" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="B" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="C" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="D" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.302,0.614" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="E" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="F" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="G" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="H" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <Button x:Name="I" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
        <ToolBar Margin="0,0,0,450.6">
            <Button Name="newButton" Click="newButton_Click">New</Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: please use words or image to express what you want other than using your own code (I mean the commented code you mentioned) which may be wrong (because you're currently asking for it).

Comment: Im showing my code to show I did some effort. But in short what I want is to set the same background color for all disabled buttons in the resource dictionary.

Comment: changing the `Template` when `IsEnabled` is `false` should work although it's some kind of overkill. You're very close to the working code, but I'm being confused about the commented code, if uncommenting them all, the code does not even compile.

Comment: If I uncomment the first commented line for example I am able to change te border, but I want to change te background and also want to keep the content(text) visible. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly more than you were looking for:

```xaml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF959595" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FFFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FFDEDEDE" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF959595" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF00B4E4" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF0083C3" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF4C7B8F" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#DBEDFD" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#C4E0FC" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#4C7B8F" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#EFEFEF" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#EFEFEF" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#D9D9D9" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BrBrush" Color="#ACACAC" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="BgBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Edit based on comments/feedback by King King**

The above example is certainly more than the OP has requested, however, considering the context of the question and their interest in `Button` control `State` styling, I felt it advantageous to provide additional detail (albeit without explanation admittedly).

Prior to `<Setter Property="Tempalte">` I am altering the basic visual style of the `Button` control.  I should hope none of this requires explaining as it seems fairly self explanatory.

Post `<Setter Property="Template">` I am altering the [visual states](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx) of the `Button` `ControlTemplate` (these being `Normal`, `MouseOver`, `Pressed` & `Disabled`).  This allows me to customise the look and feel of the `Button` whilst it is in one of these states.  In this example I am using a [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx) so that I can animate the `Button`s `State` transitions.

The four `State`s are styled in a similar format (animated gradient background & animated solid border), the differences between these states being the colours and durations they employ to provide the desired effect.

After the `VisualState`s I alter the main content template, how I want the `Button` control to be presented.  I provide a `ContentPresenter` which will be used to display the content of the `Button`, I bind certain characteristics of the `ContentPresenter` to the `Button` being template, allowing for these characteristics to be controlled on a per `Button` basis if so desired.  The `ContentPresenter` is surrounded by a `Border` which defines a `BrBrush` (boarder brush) and a `BgBrush` (background brush).  These are the same brushes that are referenced in the `VisualStates` templates and provide a default state for them to work to/from.

Finally I alter the `ControlTemplate.Triggers`, customising the visual style of the `Button` (its foreground colour in this example) based on the `Property` `Value` of the activated `Trigger`.

Comment: you're making it too complicated. Simply change the `Template` with some `ContentPresenter` should be enough. Also answering like this without any explanation (so -1 for it) is not recommended. Anyone can copy and paste the code found everywhere.

Comment: @Sybren next time please at least leave some comment under all the answers telling something about it, working or not? My code actually works but I felt a little shocked that you did not even care about it. Even a simple comment like this `This also works but I prefer the other...` will make me not disappointed (although I may  anyway delete the answer after that).

Comment: @KingKing - Agreed I provided more than was requested, however, I would not say going further is always bad.  It is also down to the OP to decide if an answer is appropriate or otherwise.  Personally I would undelete your answer, as someone else might find it better than mine. Additionally regarding your `no explanation` comment, there are numerous examples on SO of `unexplained` answers, your top 3 voted answers for example.  Just saying.

Comment: @KingKing Your answer wasn't working, I hope you make sure your answer is correct and test it before you post it. Unflux answer is more than requested but it works and it's the answer to my question.

Comment: @Sybren I ***did test it*** and it worked on my side. If it does not work for you, you should comment about it, working or not and give as much info as possible for the answerers to improve their answer. Many answers on SO have been improved to become the right solution for the OP. Remote debugging is something not easy to be sure the answer is correct without any OP's confirmation. Sometimes, they ***don't even know how*** to apply the answers in their actual code and simply complain that it's not working.